# ZendDb - Increment field with integer - Add +1

Tags: mysql, sql-update, increment, zend-db

I have the following thing: I want to update my table and increment a specific field by 1.

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_field = my_field + 1 WHERE other_field > 27
```

How can I achieve this with `ZendDB`? I'm using Version 1.

**This doesn't work:**

```
$ZDB->update("my_table",
      array('my_field' => 'my_field+1'),
      $ZDB->quoteInto("other_field > ?", 27));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found it! Thanks to this [forum link](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/How-to-Increment-a-field-by-1-using-Update-td673969.html) here is my solution:

```
$ZDB->update("my_table",
  array('my_field' => new Zend_Db_Expr('my_field+1')),
  $ZDB->quoteInto("other_field > ?", 27));
```